# Leave an Active Directory domain

Tags: active-directory

I have to leave a active directory domain for several machines.

What is happening when a user goes out the domain and connect locally on the computer?
Does he still have access to its applications (Outlook, Office) and its documents stored on the hard disk of the computer?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When taking a machine off of a domain the programs will remain in tact, as well as the files on the HDD.

The only quirks to this might be if the software on the PC is licensed using a license server on the AD domain, or maybe if there is redirected folders enabled for users.